# How to Show primary key data?

Tags: .net, datagridview, foreign-keys, datagridcolumn

I have two tables: Transactions and Accounts.

Transaction has a foreign key IDAccount from Accounts Table.

I assign datasource property of Datasource property of Datagridview to Transactions Table.

I want to Accounts.description insead of IDAccount in Datagridview.

What must I do?

Comment: Do you mean datatable? normally the value should be available in the source for it to be displayed

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution to this problem offered [here](http://www.developer-corner.com/development/dotnet/datagridview-how-to-bind-nested-objects/) which involves doing some custom code to inspect each property and determine if it belongs to the main bound object or to a child object.

This looks like a good solution except it doesn't support editing or sorting based on these properties.

Another approach (which I would probably recommend since it is simpler) is to introduce an AccountDescription property to your Transaction object.

```
public class Transaction
{
    private Account _account

    public string AccountDescription
    {
        get { return _account.description; }
        set { _account.description = value; }
    }
}
```

You might also need to implement some custom INotifyPropertyChanged code so databinding works nicely.